# Java renaming a old directory or deleting it to make a new one

Tags: java, directory

I am having an issue with a panel i am working on, what I am working on is whenever there is an upgrade from one version of the software to another the older start menu group on the windows machine still shows. I have tried to see if i can delete the old directory first and then make the new one but all that happens is the old one is still staying. Not really sure how to go about it all I need is just one directory in the start menu group to show weather I delete or rename the old.

Here is what I have so far to delete the old system variable. This is something I am working on and i know its not perfect but any help would be appreciated. If you need explanations I would be happy to comply.  Thank you

```
 if ( PrioGlobals.UPGRADE ){
        oldm_txtGrpName.setText(PrioGlobals.StartMenuFolder);
    }

if ( PrioGlobals.UPGRADE ){   
           String oldShortCutPath = PrioGlobals.cre.getShorcutDirectory();
           String oldStartMenuGroupFolderPath = oldShortCutPath + File.separator + BrandStrings.WIN_FOLDER_NAME + 
        File.separator +oldm_txtGrpName.getText(); 

           File oldStartmenu = new File(oldStartMenuGroupFolderPath);
           if (oldStartmenu.exists())
           {
               oldStartmenu.delete();
           }
           else
               oldStartmenu.delete();
           }
```

Comment: Is that directory you try to delete empty? Are you possibly swallowing the associated exception somewhere?

Comment: the directory isn't empty sadly , It has files added to it. And no i didn't add an exception to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly, `oldStartmenu` is a directory?  In that case, `oldStartmenu.delete()` will probably fail because the directory is not empty (see [File delete](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)) In which case you need to delete the directory and all of it's files recursively.

At which point I would recommend including commons-io [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and use one of the directory utilities such as [forceDelete](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete%28java.io.File%29) or [deleteDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29)

[update]

Once you have added the commons-io library to your project you would

```
// import FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

// ...

if (oldStartmenu.exists())
{
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(oldStartmenu);
}
```

Comment: Yes oldStartMenu is a directory and it isn't empty, Thank you for pointing me to those examples. Which one would you recommend would be better forceDelete or deleteDirectory?

Comment: Either should work.  If you are sure it is a directory use deleteDirectory.  If it might be a file or a directory use forceDelete.

Comment: its a directory . and it would delete everything withen the directory right? And could you provide an example of how I would do it ? I dont understand well with the example you showed me on deletedirectory.

Comment: If i can't use the commons-io FileUtils ? how would i do it in another way?

Comment: You would have to write it yourself. Of course - it's pretty easy to find the source code to FileUtils.java.  You could look at the source code for deleteDirectory and see how they do it.  Not that I would ever recommending just lifting the source code because that might be a copyright violation.

Comment: Yeah , problem is i cant find where to download the file sadly for the io-commons lol. Sad i know i should be able to find it and download it but i can't find the file for downloading it.

Comment: Hint - start here and work your way down http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/